# Visual Studio 2010: How refer to a C# .Net class library project with third part dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll

This is probably a very basic question but I haven't found any detailed information about how project references works in Visual Studio.

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C# solution containing a MainApp project and a C# class library project with third party assemblies inside. When referring to the class library project from the MainApp project, should I just add a project reference or do I need to add references to the third party assemblies within the class library project as well?

In some cases it seems like the third party assemblies are not loaded correctly if I just have the Class Library project reference in my MainApp project although all DLL files (incl third party DLLs) show up in the output folder when building the complete solution.

**Edit:** I've posted a more specific question since the general answer did not help in my case: [How to refer self-contained C# class library project with IronPython inside (Visual Studio 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992481/how-to-refer-self-contained-c-sharp-class-library-project-with-ironpython-inside)

Comment: Dont you get compile time errors if you don't reference the 3rd party dlls induvidually?

Comment: How is the relation done here? I mean, lets call your main app as Project A. Now you have a Project B which is having assembly references with 3rd party assemblies right? So now, is Project A also using these 3rd party assem directly or via Project B? If via project B, then just add Project B as proj ref in Proj A.

Comment: Yes it's like zenwalker's second assumption: 3rd party assemblies are only used via Project B. No compilation errors, but still run time problems in some cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using thrid party assemblies/dlls I find it bect to create a folder in a project called "Dependencies" and place them in there, that way they don't get lost or hidden in amongst your source.

Your class library project should reference the thrid party assemblies. You'll need to browse for those (after clicking add reference) and then set the `Copy Local` property `True`, that way they will be copied to the directory into which any compiled code is placed.

Your other project just needs to reference your class library project(remember to set the `Copy Local` property), select it from the Projects list after clicking **add reference**.

Oh I forgot to add your code files that refer to any publics on the referenced assemblies will require a `using` statement to link to them.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that your last tip about adding the using statement would do the trick for me but I still have some problems. I'll accept this answer since I think it's the correct answer in the general case. Then I'll add a specific question for my problem that is related to IronPython.

Comment: I thought that referencing project B (from project A), and project C is referenced from project B, then just referencing project b should compile and copy project b and project c to the output folder of project a. But it doesnt it seems.